# Identify string in dataframe and replace content using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, identity

I have a csv file and I loaded using Pandas. Firstly I decide to rename the columns. The dataframe is this:

[image]

My goal is to check if all the columns of each row contain the following characters `\n`. If so, the cells of the row containing the previously mentioned string must be modified in such a way that the only content left is what comes after `\n`. The output of such algorithm should be like this:

[image]

The code so far is this but I got stuck on finding and removing \n along with what precedes it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('prova.csv', sep=',', skiprows=0, header=None,low_memory=False)
df.columns = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if '\n' in row[?]:
        # how do I remove the unwanted characters for each cell?
```

Notice: I want to investigate all the columns, not only those where `\n` appears.

```
A    object
B    object
C    object
D    object
E     int64
F    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Please don't post images to share data. Paste the data and format it as code instead.

Comment: Why all these downvotes... my question is pretty legit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solution***
Use `str` accessor with `split` after `stack` to get a series.

```
df.astype(str).stack().str.split('\n').str[-1].unstack()
```

[image]

---

#### Setup Reference

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['bello', 'bot', 'corpo', '105', 245, 'Yes'],
        ['bello', 'par\nsot', 'testo\ncorpo', '105', 660, 'Yes\nno'],
        ['bello', 'pic\nhot', 'fallo', '195\n250', 660, 'Yes'],
        ['bello', 'hot', 'fallo\nbacca', '105', 245, 'Yes']
    ], columns=list('ABCDEF'))
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use `applymap` with `str.split` to split on `\n` char and take the last split:

```
df['E'] = df['E'].astype(str)
df.applymap(lambda x: x.split('\n')[-1])
```

[image]

One liner:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x.split('\n')[-1] if type(x)==str else x)
```

Comment: Hi! When I try your solution I get this error: ("'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'split'", 'occurred at index E') how is it possible?

Comment: You need to have all your columns as `string` objects for it to work. Check the `dtypes` and convert those integer columns to `str` using `astype(str`).

Comment: I converted as you mentioned and I no longer get any error message but nothing happens... the dataframe keeps being as it was... how is possible?

Comment: It's working fine for me in Python `3.5`, Pandas`0.18.1`.

Comment: I have: Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] - Pandas '0.18.0'

Comment: I think it could be an issue with your `csv` file. Could you also include a sample of it along with your post and do not paste an image?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to remove anything before a '\n' (or any other character you specify) from a string:

```
import re
str="onetwo\nthree"
print(str)
test = re.search('(?<=\\n)\w+', str)
print(test.group(0))
```